# HTA Prompt/VB Code - Trying to have 2 dropdowns show up

Tags: vb.net, hta

I have an HTA prompt that is using VB code. I need to have two dropdowns shown on the table. For some reason, only the second dropdown is showing up for "Select sector." It works fine when there was only one dropdown, but when I added the second for sector, it removed the first for location. How do I get both dropdowns to show up so it is like:

Select your current location: [DROPDOWN]

Select your sector: [DROPDOWN]

```
    'AA Sites
Function startSTAGE3()
    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
    LASTSTAGE = STAGE   
    bodystring = "<br>Select your current location: <SELECT SIZE='.5' NAME='Clocation' ONCHANGE='LOCCHANGED()'>"
    bodystring = bodystring & "<option value='0'>&nbsp;</option>"
    bodystring = bodystring & "<option value='MacDill AFB, FL, APO, AA'"
    If locationindex = 1 Then bodystring = bodystring & " selected"
    bodystring = bodystring & ">MacDill AFB, FL, APO, AA</option></SELECT>"
    bodystring = "<br><br><br>Select your sector: <SELECT SIZE='.3' NAME='Csector' ONCHANGE='SECTORCHANGED()'>"
    bodystring = bodystring & "<option value='0'>&nbsp;</option>"
    bodystring = bodystring & "<option value='ES'"
    If sectorindex = 1 Then bodystring = bodystring & " selected"
    bodystring = bodystring & ">ES</option><option value='L&A'"
    If sectorindex = 2 Then bodystring = bodystring & " selected"
    bodystring = bodystring & ">L&A</option><option value='I&S'"
    If sectorindex = 3 Then bodystring = bodystring & " selected"
    bodystring = bodystring & ">I&S</option><option value='S2'"
    If sectorindex = 4 Then bodystring = bodystring & " selected"
    bodystring = bodystring & ">S2</option><option value='INC'"
    If sectorindex = 5 Then bodystring = bodystring & " selected"
    bodystring = bodystring & ">INC</option></SELECT>"

    Function SECTORCHANGED()
        ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
        currentsector = Csector(Csector.selectedIndex).Value
        sectorindex = Csector.selectedIndex
    End Function

    Function LOCCHANGED()
        ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
        currentlocation = Clocation(Clocation.selectedIndex).Value
        locationindex = Clocation.selectedIndex
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you are missing an `End Function` for your first function.

**Second**, instead of using :

```
bodystring = bodystring & [...]
```

I rather suggest :

```
bodystring += [...]
```

It is much easier to read and clusters much less your code.

**Third**, you overwrite your `bodystring` before using it here :

```
bodystring = bodystring & ">MacDill AFB, FL, APO, AA</option></SELECT>"
'The next commands overwrites bodystring before it is being used
bodystring = "<br><br><br>Select your sector: <SELECT SIZE='.3' NAME='Csector' ONCHANGE='SECTORCHANGED()'>"
bodystring = bodystring & "<option value='0'>&nbsp;</option>"
bodystring = bodystring & "<option value='ES'"
```

This may be the error.

#### Edit1

I also suggest using

```
If [condition] then
'[stuff to do]
ElseIf [condition] then
'[stuff to do]
ElseIf [condition] then
'[stuff to do]
End If
```

Instead of your inline `If`s.